# Angular 2: Easy way to turn on/off a directive?

Tags: angular

An attribute directive:

```
<div myDirective>
     My content
    </div>
```

I want to modify myDirective as little as possible.

EDIT: myDirective listens to mouse movements. I want it to ignore mouse movements when it is turned off. I hope to not use an input boolean value that will need to be checked before every mouse movement.

EDIT: Here is my directive code. I am just trying to find out if I can make myDirective turn on/off without adding lots of if conditions for the Renderer events. Hasn't Angular made a simple way to turn on/off directives, or does someone know a trick?

```
import { Directive, Output, Input, HostListener, EventEmitter,  ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[pan]' })
export class myDirective {
    private _clicking: boolean = false;
    private _previousX: number;
    private _previousY: number;

    constructor(private _el: ElementRef, private _renderer: Renderer) { }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this._renderer.listen(this._el.nativeElement, 'mousedown', (e: any) => {

            e.preventDefault();
            this._previousX = e.clientX;
            this._previousY = e.clientY;
            this._clicking = true;

        });



        this._renderer.listen(this._el.nativeElement, 'mouseup', (e:  any) => {

            this._clicking = false;

        });


        this._renderer.listen(this._el.nativeElement, 'mousemove',  (e: any) => {

            if (this._clicking) {
                e.preventDefault();
                let directionX: number = (this._previousX - e.clientX) > 0 ? 1 : -1;
                let directionY: number = (this._previousY - e.clientY) > 0 ? 1 : -1;
                this._el.nativeElement.scrollLeft += (this._previousX - e.clientX);
                this._el.nativeElement.scrollTop += (this._previousY - e.clientY);
                this._previousX = e.clientX;
                this._previousY = e.clientY;
            }


        });


        this._renderer.listen(this._el.nativeElement, 'mouseleave', (e: any) => {

            this._clicking = false;

        });

}



}
```

Comment: Delete `myDirective`?

Comment: Can you add the directive code?

Comment: A boolean will need to be checked every time no mater what

Comment: Rather than checking before every mouse movement, you could use the `OnChange` interface to bind/unbind the event when the value of a boolean value changes.

Comment: Hey ZanattMan and Adam, please see my edits.

Comment: Edited again, to change HostListener to Renderer in my post's comment.

Comment: If you really don't want to change your directive, I would recommend @ZanattMan's solution, it will destroy the directive altogether based on a boolean condition. Just remember to 'unlisten' to all your listens in your `ngOnDestroy()`.

Comment: How do I delete the directive?

Comment: By using `*ngIf`, if the `div` tag doesn't show, the directive is destroyed.

Comment: That won't work since my div tag encloses the video I will be panning through the attribute directive. The video needs to show at all times, even if panning does not work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135811/discussion-between-adam-and-coder).

Answer (score 2):

```
<div *ngIf="show" myDirective>
     My content
</div>
```

In the component:

```
show:boolean;
```

With this, you will skip the directive if you are not interested in. If not, you can make something like this:

```
<div >
    <div *ngIf="show" myDirective> </div>
     <span> My content </span>
</div>
```

Comment: In order for `My content` to still render, you'd also need `<div *ngIf="!show">
     My content
</div>`

Comment: Hi Adam and ZanattMan, please see the edit to my question.

Comment: @coder does it solve your problem? If so, can you mark it a solved so others can use it?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply pass a variable into the directive. See the [Angular 2 docs here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html#!#bindings) for an example of how to pass data in.

```
<div [myDirective]="shouldShow">My Content</div>
```

Where `shouldShow` is a boolean value if the directive should execute or not.

Then in your directive you can read the data from `[myDirective]`.

```
@Input() myDirective: boolean;
```

This modifies `myDirective`, but also removes potential duplication from your template that could result from using `*ngIf`.